# PyLint W0108: Lambda may not be > necessary (unnecessary-lambda)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

pylint is returning the below message for the code that I have below :

> data.py:125:30: W0108: Lambda may not be
>   necessary (unnecessary-lambda)

```
in_p = ', '.join(list(map(lambda x: "'{}'".format(x), data)))
```

Why is lambda not required here and how can it be refactored?

Comment: What is the context where `in_p` gets used? There may be a preferable alternative to manually producing a comma-separate list of single-quoted values in the first place.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`"'{}'".format` is already a function; your lambda expression defines a function that does nothing except take an argument and pass it on to another function. You can simply write

```
in_p = ', '.join(list(map("'{}'".format, data)))
```

Some might prefer to use a list comprehension here:

```
in_p = ', '.join(["'{}'".format(x) for x in data])
```

It might also be worth using a temporary variable for readability.

```
quote_it = "'{}'".format
in_p = ', '.join(list(map(quote_it, data)))
# in_p = ', '.join([quote_it(x) for x in data])
```

Comment: Thanks @chepner! This helps. Is there an advantage of using list comprehension instead of map function in this use case?

Comment: I think the list comprehension syntax is a little cleaner, and they are "generally" preferred over `map`. `', '.join(map("'{}'".format, data))` would also be fine, though slightly less efficient given that you are passing a generator, not a list, to `join`.

Comment: No need fo the extra list. The generator is enough: `in_p = ', '.join("'{}'".format(x) for x in data)`

Comment: @Netwave It's more efficient to give `join` a list. It has to iterate over its argument twice: once to determine how much space to allocate for the resulting string, and again to actually produce the string. Building a list with a list comprehension is faster than building one up from an arbitrary generator inside `join`.

Comment: @chepner, wow, that is quite interesting. Can you point me in any documentation about that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Aside from looking at the source code for `str.join`, no,

Comment: Note that replacing `lambda x: f(x)` with `f` is called "eta-reduction" (or "η-reduction"): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#%CE%B7-reduction (doing the opposite is called "eta-expansion", which compilers sometimes do)